# Unable to bind item property in itemcontainerstyle

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, itemscontrol

I created a .NET WPF Application with MvvmLight this evening. I'm trying to show a couple of circles on my main window.

My MainWindow.xaml is bound to MainViewModel.cs. MainViewModel contains an ObservableCollection with SpaceObjects. I'm trying to show this collection using itemcontrols.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SpaceObjects}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding }"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Radius}"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Ellipse Width="{Binding Radius}" Height="{Binding Radius}" Fill="Blue" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

</ItemsControl>
```

In the ItemTemplate I am able to bind to a SpaceObject property (like Radius). In ItemContainerStyle I can only choose from the context:
[image]

I would like to choose from the items in the source (ItemsScourse SpaceObjects), so I can bind the X and Y coordinates from the circle. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where are X and Y ? MainViewModel or SpaceObjects ? if SpaceObjects has them , try to write {Binding SpaceObjects.X}

Comment: X and Y are specified in each SpaceObject. SpaceObjects.X does not work.